# C# CSV get rid of the diameters that are not needed

Tags: c#, csv

Hi there I got this problem, and I hope you can help me.

I got a *CSV file*, and in there are lines like this.

---

```
Username|||Password||Email   (thats the header)

tUser1|||||asdf||temail@gmail.com

tUser2|||qwer|temali2@gmail.com

tUser3|zxcv|temail3@gmail.com
```

---

and I need to get rid of the unnecessary `|` in the lines...

to get something like this:

---

```
Username|Password|Email   
tUser1|asdf|temail@gmail.com
tUser2|qwer|temali2@gmail.com
tUser3|zxcv|temail3@gmail.com
```

Comment: That's not CSV – *comma* separated value. But even so, the best way to do this is to avoid multiple delimiters at source (otherwise you have ambiguity between repeated separators and empty fields).

Answer (score 2):

You could `split` the string first, then `join` it back

```
foreach(string line in lines)//or while(!sr.EndOfStream) depends on how you iterate each line
{
    string[] x = line.Split('|');
    string show = string.Join("|", x.Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `string.Split` ([Here on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131448(v=vs.110).aspx)) and specify `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` as the second parameter.  This will return you an array containing the non-empty delimited values for the string you split.  So you'll be looking at something like

```
string[] parsedLine = thisLine
  .Split(new char[] {'|'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

If you lines follow your example, `parsedLine[0]` will contain the username, `parsedLine[1]` their password, and `parsedLine[2]` their email address.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is using *regular expressions*, just a simple direct pattern `@"\|{2,}"` (two or many '|') replacing by single `"|"`:

```
  String source = @"tUser1|||||asdf||temail@gmail.com";

  // "tUser1|asdf|temail@gmail.com"
  String result = Regex.Replace(source, @"\|{2,}", "|");
```

For the entire file:

```
 var data = File
   .ReadLines(@"C:\MyFile.txt")
   .Select(line => Regex.Replace(line, @"\|{2,}", "|"));

 File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\MyClearedFile.txt", data);
```